# Query to find the ID of any student that has taken an exam in a module without taking the prerquisite modules

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

As the title says I'm trying to output the ID of any student who has taken an exam in a module without having taken an exam for the prerequisite modules.

The tables I'm using are called student, exam and prerequisites and are laid out like so:

```
STUDENT

Student_name | Student_id | Course_name | Year

Exam

Student_id | Module_code | Exam_year | Score

PREREQUISITES

Module_code | Prerequisite_code
```

There are other tables e.g. Module which is used for the foreign keys module_code and prerequisite_code in prerquisites however I don't believe it is relevant to this problem.

I have queries to gain each individual part of the problem i.e. Student_id, Module_code and prerequisite code

```
SELECT student_id FROM student;

SELECT Module_code FROM exam WHERE Student_id = <EachPreviousFoundID>;

SELECT Prerequisite_code FROM prerequisites WHERE Module_code = <EachPreviousFoundModule>;
```

However I'm not sure how to bind these three queries together to create one query which will find the module code of every exam taken by each particular student and then ensure they have also taken the prerequisite modules.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This look like homework as all your questions. Have you seen [**JOIN**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) examples?

Comment: try to `join` or `in` and `not in` conditions. Give it a try and post what you was able to obtain. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to do it using collections:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TYPE stringlist IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
/
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT e.student_id,
       t.COLUMN_VALUE AS module_code,
       p.prerequisites MULTISET EXCEPT e.modules_taken AS missing_prerequisites
FROM   ( -- All the modules each student has taken.
         SELECT student_id,
                CAST( COLLECT( module_code ) AS stringlist ) AS modules_taken
         FROM   exam
         GROUP BY student_id
       ) e,
       TABLE( e.modules_taken ) t,
       ( -- All the prerequisites for each module
         SELECT module_code,
                CAST( COLLECT( prerequisite_code ) AS stringlist ) AS prerequisites
         FROM   prerequisites
         GROUP BY module_code
       ) p
WHERE  t.COLUMN_VALUE = p.module_code
AND    p.prerequisites MULTISET EXCEPT e.modules_taken IS NOT EMPTY;
```